# Is WSO2 carbon container is secure enough?

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can any one please tell whether WSO2carbon container is secure enough to use as it is using tomcat as embedded container? As we know tomcat is not secure enough. We wanted to convince our client to use it but only we have to proof that it is safe enough though it is using tomcat.

Please help!!!

Comment: If already tomcat is not secure enough for you, I doubt that wso2carbon will be. But what is the exact reason that you say "tomcat is not secure"?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Tomcat is not secure enough can you provide some examples.

Comment: Can you explain why you are you saying that tomcat is not secure?

Comment: My Client is stressing to use WebLogic server for every deployment we do.  They feel WebLogic is more secure than Tomcat. We don't have any way to deploy API manager as a war on WebLogic. It comes with embedded Tomcat. In net also I found WebLogic is more secure than Tomcat.We have 2 options either I will make API manager as war and deploy to any application server which seems difficult or I will have to showcase something about WSO2 carbon container saying it is secure enough to use!! Please help..